# Where are finite verbs in these sentences?

Tags: grammar

I found these sentences from the internet.

1.Finite verbs usually follow their subjects: 
He **coughs**.

The documents **had compromised** him.

They **will have gone**.

This web said that the bolded segments above are finite verbs

2.The girls were talking to each other loudly.

The second web said that  **were** is **finite verb** and **talking** is  **non-finite verb**

I’m confused where finite verbs are.

Comment: You're confused because the two websites are using different definitions of finite verbs. One is calling the entire multi-word form of the verb a "finite verb". The other is just calling the finite part of the multi-word form of the verb the "finite verb".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [usingenglish.com](http://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/finite-verb.html)...

> The finite forms of a verb are the forms where the verb shows *tense, person* or *singular plural*.
>    Non-finite verb forms have no person, tense or number.
>
> ***finite** I go, she goes, he went.*
>    ***non-finite*** To go, going (the infinitive, and the gerund/present participle).

Thus in OP's first three examples, ***coughs, had compromised, will have gone*** are "finite" forms of the verbs ***to cough, to compromise, to go***. In the second and third cases, the [modal auxiliary verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb) ***will*** and ***had/have*** are the only ways in English to indicate verb [**tense, aspect,** and **modality**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb#Tense.2C_aspect.2C_and_modality), apart from the endings **-s** (present tense, third person singular), **-ed** (past tense), and **-ing** ("continuous" aspect).

In OP's last example, ***were*** is a "tensed" (finite) form indicating *past* action and *plural* subject (or [second person singular "you"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_person)). So those verb forms change for *present* activity or *singular* subject, but the "non-finite" present participle ***talking*** doesn't...

> *The girls **were** talking to John.* (past action, plural subject)
>   *The girls **are** talking to us.* (present action, plural subject)
>   *John **was** talking to me.* (past action, singular subject)
>   *John **is** talking to you.* (present action, singular subject)

Also note that it makes no difference whether the [object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28grammar%29) *(John, us, me, you)* is singular or plural.